# For loop separate $i's

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Hi I want to have "NOTHING HERE" to come out of the for loop but I get NOTHING and HERE

> pi@ed_pi:~ $ cat test.txt
>
> NOTHING HERE
>
> pi@ed_pi:~ $ for i in `cat test.txt`; do echo $i; done
>
> NOTHING
>
> HERE
>
> pi@ed_pi:~ $

What am I doing wrong ?

Why are we getting 2 separate $i's ?

Thanks

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get two loop iteration because that is how

```
for i in value1 value2; do ...
```

works. You may want

```
for i in "value1 value2"; do ...
```

in which case you need

```
for i in "$(cat test.txt)"; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: Thanks very much the "for i in "$(cat test.txt)"; do echo $i; done" did the trick.